# Extend router type in Nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

How do I extend the router type in Nuxt 3? I'm using a query as an object, and I'm encountering a type error: 'Object literal may only specify known properties, and query does not exist in type NavigationGuardNextCallback'.

Example:

```
query: {
  filter: {
    name: string,
    age: number,
  },
  page: number,
  perPage: number,
}
```

[image]

In Vue 3, I can do something like this:

```
// shims-vue-router.d.ts
import { Router as VueRouter } from 'vue-router';

declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface Router extends VueRouter {
    push(to: RouteLocationRaw | object): Promise<NavigationFailure | void | undefined>;
  }
}
```